# Can I used regex with filedata.replace()? Or can I use filedata.replace() on a specific location?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to find and replace SSNs in several text files, I know the exact location in the file where the SSN will start, and I know what will proceed it.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import os, glob

files = glob.glob("filepath")
filein = files[0]
print(filein)

f = open(filein,'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

#this is where I need help:
newdata = filedata.replace("-SSN-","121231234")

f = open(filein,'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

I couldn't find (via google) any way to replace at a certain position, so I figured regex would be better, but I'm not sure if I can use regex in the filedata.replace() method.

Thanks

Comment: No, this is what the `re` package is for. Use `re.sub`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the only thing in *any* of Python's standard library or built-in functions or methods that uses regular expressions are the functions and methods in the `re` module itself.  It's a pretty handy fact to keep in the back of one's head - it prevents me from attempting regex where it probably won't work.